# Show that every $A \in SL_3-$action has at least 3 fixed points on $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-actions

Consider the natural action of $SL_3(\mathbb{C})$ on $\mathbb{P}^2$ via: 
$$
SL_3(\mathbb{C}) \times  \mathbb{P}^2 \to \mathbb{P}^2, \ (A,[v]\mapsto [Av]).
$$

It is clear that the kernel of the action is a group of scalar matrices with unit determinant, i.e. Kernel $K=C_3$ is a cyclic group generated by a third root of unity. Obviously, for any element in $K$ every point in $\mathbb{P}^2$ is a fixed point.

**I want to prove that every element  $A \in SL_3$ has at least 3 fixed points on $\mathbb{P}^2$ which don't lie on a projective line.** To prove the statement, I just tried to find the points $[v]\in \mathbb{P}^2$ such that 
$$
[Av]=[v].
$$

This means that I need to find $v\in \mathbb{C}^3$ such that $Av=\lambda v$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}^*.$ The first requirement for not being on a projective line is that the vectors $v$ have to be linearly independent. But there can only be three linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{C}^3$. Thus, I think I need to show that 
$$
\dim_{\mathbb{C}} Kernel(A-\lambda I) = 3
$$

where $I$ denotes the $3\times 3$ identity matrix. This means every vector in $\mathbb{C}^3$ is in the kernel. But I don't seem to reach to the conclusion. Is the claim in the bold letters correct? How can I prove it? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

**Theorem**. Considering ${\rm GL}(V)$'s induced action on ${\Bbb P}(V)$, for any $A\in{\rm GL}(V)$ we have

$${\Bbb P}(V)^A=\bigsqcup_{\lambda\ne0}\Bbb P(V_\lambda). \tag{$\circ$}$$

Here $V$ is a finite-dimensional complex vector space and $V_\lambda$ is the $\lambda$-eigenspace for $A$ (the space of all eigenvectors of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$). Note that $V=\bigoplus V_\lambda$ does *not* always hold true; instead it holds true with *generalized* eigenspaces. The equality is equivalent to $A$ being diagonalizable. Note further that different eigenspaces have different eigenvalues, so it doesn't make sense to analyze an operator $A-\lambda\,{\rm Id}_V$ for just one value of $\lambda$ (indeed if that operator were to have kernel of dimension $\dim V$, it would be the zero map and $A=\lambda\,{\rm Id}_V$).

If $[v]\in{\Bbb P}(V)$ is a fixed point under $A$ then $[v]=A[v]=[Av]$ implies $Av=\lambda v$ for some nonzero scalar $\lambda$. Thus, fixed points correspond to eigenvectors (modulo scalars) and thus the decomposition given in $(\circ)$ follows. Note this implies $\Bbb P(V)^A\subseteq{\Bbb P}(\bigoplus_{\lambda\ne0}V_\lambda)$, and thus:

**Corollary**. There are $\dim V$ points in $\Bbb P(V)^A$ that are not in ${\Bbb P}(W)$ for any $W$ a proper subspace, if and only if $A$ is diagonalizable, in which case such sets of points are precisely those represented by a linearly independent set of eigenvectors.

If $A$ is diagonalizable and $\dim(V_\lambda)>1$ for some $\lambda$ (equivalently, if $A$'s characteristic polynomial has a repeated root) then $|{\Bbb P}(V_\lambda)|$ will be uncountable, so it will be possible to choose countably many fixed points contained in this proper projective subspace too.

Comment: What does the notation $\mathbb{P}(V)^A$ at the top mean ?

Comment: If $G$ acts on a set $X$ and $g\in G$ the notation $X^g$ denotes the elements of $X$ which are fixed by $g$.

Comment: Thanks! One more thing is not clear: By writing $A$ in a Jordan Normal form, we observe that eigenvalues $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{C}^*, \ \forall i=1,2,...,n.$ It is important that $\lambda_i \neq 0$ because we don't have $[0]$ in the projective space. If all eigenvalues are distinct, then the eigenvectors are linearly independent, and we are done. If some eigenvalue has multiplicity greater than one, how does one deal with the situation? We will then have *generalized* eigenvectors. But I had to show the existence of eigenvectors. Isn't it? (This part is not clear from your answer.)

Comment: My answer says what happens for ***any*** choice of $A\in{\rm GL}(V)$. It says what the fixed points of any $A$ are, and it says precisely for what $A$ there exist $\dim V$ points in $\Bbb P(V)$ not contained in $\Bbb P(W)$ for any proper subspace $W$. Is there a part of my answer your don't understand?

Comment: In your answer, I understand what the fixed points are, i.e. the statement in the theorem. It's not clear to me why there are $\dim(V)$ points in $\mathbb{P}(V)^A$. Of course if $A$ is diagonalizable we are done. But why is $A$ diagonalizable? Also, I don't understand the corollary and the last statement in your answer: why are you taking proper subspaces? Sorry for too many questions.

Comment: I now understand the corollary and why you are taking subspaces. Just claiming that the fixed points do not lie in a projective line, right? But it's not clear why the matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: Wait, in the last paragraph did you mean "if A is *not* diagonalizable" ? This confused me.

Comment: First: "But why is $A$ diagonalizable?" I never said $A$ is diagonalizable. You can't prove an arbitrary element of ${\rm GL}(V)$ (or ${\rm SL}_3(\Bbb C)$ for that matter) is diagonalizable, because such elements are not necessarily diagonalizable. Notice what I'm saying implies your desired claim is **not true** if $A$ is not diagonalizable. If $A$ is not diagonalizable, then all fixed points belong to $\Bbb P(\bigoplus_{\lambda\ne0}V_\lambda)$, which is proper.

Comment: Second, your **question** is asking, given an $A\in{\rm SL}(\Bbb C^3)$, if there exist $3$ fixed points in ${\Bbb P}(\Bbb C^3)$ which are not contained in $\Bbb P(V)$ for any $2$-dimensional (equivalently, proper) subspace $V$ of $\Bbb C^3$. My **answer** says, given an $A\in{\rm GL}(V)$, precisely when there exist $\dim V$ fixed points in ${\Bbb P}(V)$ that are not contained in ${\Bbb P}(W)$ for any proper subspace $W$ of $V$. My answer has as a special case the conclusion to your question, when $V=\Bbb C^3$.

Comment: This is my generalization of your question. Note that if $n$ fixed points are not contained in any projective subspace, then in particular they are not contained in any projective line, but the converse is not true, so there is a decision that needs to be made when generalizing your original claim to higher dimensions, a decision that I made by picking proper subspaces rather than sticking to just projective lines.

Comment: Finally, no, in my last paragraph I meant if $A$ is diagonalizable, just as stated. My last paragraph is pointing out that even though you can find $\dim V$ fixed points not contained in any proper projective subspace (which requires $A$ to be diagonalizable, hence my comment to that effect), if further an eigenvalue has nontrivial multiplicity then you can *also* find $\dim V$ points that do *not* satisfy these requirements, indeed you can find infinitely many points all in the same projective line (namely a projective line within ${\Bbb P}(V_\lambda)$ if $\dim V_\lambda>1$).

Comment: So basically your answer requires $A$ to be diagonalizable. That is you are saying my claim is not true if the matrix is not diagonalizable. Correct?

Comment: My answer does not require $A$ to be diagonalizable. My answer says what the fixed points of $A$ are regardless of whether or not $A$ is diagonalizable (the decomposition in $(\circ)$ does not require anything of $A$). But your claim (that three fixed points of a $A\in{\rm SL}_3(\Bbb C)$ not contained in any projective line exist) is false if $A$ is not diagonalizable.